# How to prevent a 'hidden' link to an image within a #if condition in MediaWiki

Tags: templates, mediawiki

We have an image which has a predictably-positioned number in the filename.  I handle the display of the image in a template based on whether or not the number is within multiple different ranges.  If it is in any of those ranges, the image does not (and should not) exist.

Everything works fine, but I find that Special:WantedFiles still includes a listing for the intentionally 'missing' images.  The sole link for each 'missing' file is from the page that is using that template.  It seems that, even though the page correctly isn't trying to display the image, the wiki still is *also* interpreting the [[File:foobar]] bit as if the #if test were resolving the other way, creating an unused link to a non-existant file.

The following is a simplified version of the problem part of the template.  ImageRangeTest is the range check template; it works fine, returning either a 0 or a 1 depending on if the {{{1}}} number is in any of the matching ranges.

```
{{#ifeq: {{ImageRangeTest | {{{1}}} }} | 1 | This image does not exist. | [[File:{{{1}}}.png]] }}
```

So why, when ImageRangeTest returns 1, does "This image does not exist." properly get displayed, but File:{{{1}}}.png still get a hidden link from that same page, causing File:{{{1}}}.png to show up on Special:WantedFiles?

Comment: It won't cause a hidden link. There is probably something else somewhere else in that template doing that.

Answer (score 1):

What you want do is not possible currently. It's a 'hidden' link to you, but a normal link to the database. [The table](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Imagelinks_table) storing file inclusions does not differentiate on whether the image exists or not. Special:WantedFiles generates its content by querying that table among others.

Various requests to change this were declined as per back as 2006, such as [this](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T6572) and [this](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T8011). Not the request were mostly about general links generated from templates but the underlying problem/issue is the samae as yours.

The only way to stop it from showing in that special page is to delink the name, that's to remove the square brackets, and I doubt if you'd like that.

Comment: Those tasks are about different issues. False branches of the `#if*` parserfunctions do not get evaluated and do not update the imagelinks table.

Comment: After much testing, it turned out to be the fact that I was assigning the value to a #var: {{#vardefine:foo|{{#ifeq: {{ImageRangeTest | {{{1}}} }} | 1 | This image does not exist. | [[File:{{{1}}}.png]] }} }}.  Something about all of that was triggering the bous entries.  Taking out the #var assignment cleared the problem.